# Correct way to pass index of params Rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following search function defined in my model:

```
class CoffeeType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :coffee_items

   def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}")
    else
      where(nil)
    end
  end 
end
```

and have the following RSpec test:

```
 describe "GET index with serach params" do
       it 'renders a list of Coffee Types' do
         get :index, {search: "Ame"}, valid_session
         assigns(:coffee_types).count.should eq(2)
       end
    end
```

This is probably pretty much trivial and am not seeing the bigger picture here.

Comment: Are you using factories or seeding your test database?

Comment: The discrepancy between the console and the test is because when you're starting up the console, unless you're passing `RAILS_ENV=test`, you're using the development database. Running tests will use an entirely different database (for the `test` environment), so you're getting 0 results because there are no `coffee_types` in that database.

Comment: @gregates: Makes sense enough, so having said that I can load my seeded data into my test db by putting the following in the top of my `load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"` ?

Comment: As gregates said - you don't have matches because you don't have that data in the database.  To test what you actually have in the database, you'd have to search for "ESP" and have a count of 1 - note that for more user friendly searches you should make your search case insensitive.

Comment: Or just do `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: A more common solution would be to use fixtures as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures or factories (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl is a popular gem for the latter solution).

Comment: @gregates I stand correct I do have a factory for this particular model. Forgot to include see my update

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See here for an explanation of the default rspec `use_transactional_fixtures` setting:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions

Unless you've changed this configuration, your database is reset after every example. So you need to actually set up the initial state in the example/example group. In your case that might look something like:

```
describe "GET index with serach params" do
  before :each do
    # create two coffee_types that should be found by searching for "Ame" and
    # one that shouldn't
    2.times { FactoryGirl.create :coffee_type }
    FactoryGirl.create :coffee_type, name: "Espresso" 
  end  

  it 'renders a list of Coffee Types' do
    get :index, {search: "Ame"}, valid_session
    assigns(:coffee_types).count.should eq(2)
  end
end
```

Edit: Duh! Actually, the code in your model method is incorrect. You've only got the `%` wildcard *before* the search term. Change that line to:

`where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")`

Comment: See my edit above. Also, though, in the gist the name that gets assigned in your factory is different than it is in the code in the OP: it's "Mocha", which won't match "Ame" even with the extra `%`